# Expected '(', '{' or <string>, got 'GUI'

Tags: roblox

I was following a loading screen tutorial but it seems that a part of the code is wrong.

```
game.ReplicatedFirst:RemoveDefaultLoadingScreen()

local PlayerGui = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
PlayerGui:SetTopBarTransparency(0)

local GUI = script.LoadingScreen:Clone
GUI.Parent = PlayerGui --<<-- This part of the script is the part that is causing it

repeat wait(1) until game:IsLoaded()

GUI.Frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 0, 1,0),"InOut","Sine",0.5)
wait(0.5)
GUI:Destroy()
```

Comment: Was this one of Roblox's tutorials on the develop.roblox.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is telling you that it expected some parentheses, but instead found the next line.
`Clone` is a function, and needs to be called like one :

```
local GUI = script.LoadingScreen:Clone()
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add those